# Floating Action Button not visible on application start

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I have a fragment with a RecyclerView inside of a ViewPager, and I want to manage the behavior of a Floating Action Button located in my MainActivity. In my onCreateView() of the Fragment, I have the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);
    recycler = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    initiate_recycler();
    if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).set_fab_behavior(recycler);
    }
    return v;
}
```

In the MainActivity, I have the set_fab_behavior() method, which is:

```
public void set_fab_behavior(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy < 0) {
                fab.show();
            } else {
                fab.hide();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The code works fine, and it shows/hides the Floating Action Button when it is scrolled. However, the fab isn't initialized when the app first runs. It isn't there, and when the RecyclerView is scrolled for the first time, it doesn't animate in. Instead, it just appears. How should I modify the code so the fab is present on the application start?

Also, note that the fab works fine when this method is not called, but it doesn't hide on scroll, which is necessary. I already tried passing the fab to the fragment via a getter method, and adding the OnScrollListener in the fragment, but the results were the same.

Edit: below is the MainActivity layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.gworkman.shoutout.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic"
        app:elevation="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout code of MainActivity ?

Comment: @JavT I posted it